# Merge two arrays of hashes based on comparison of multiple keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays of hashes:

```
a1 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@hotmail.com" }, ...]
a2 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", ORDER_NO: 5511426 }, ...]
```

I would like to find the hashes in `a2` whose `ID` and `name` fields match the `ID` and `name` fields of an entry in `a1` (without caring about `email` or any other items that make their way into `a2`), and then merge the value of `ORDER_NO` into the `a1` hash at those values.  i.e. end up with:

```
[{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@example.com", ORDER_NO: 5511426 } ...]
```

Also I want to ignore elements present in a2 but not in a1.

I'm doing the following:

```
a1.each do |a1_hash|
  matching_hash = a2.find { |a2_hash| data_matches?(a1_hash, a2_hash) } if a2.present?
  a1_hash["ORDER_NO"] = a2_hash["ORDER_NO"] if matching_hash.present?
  a2.delete(a2_hash)
end
```

but is there a faster way?

Comment: What should happen if `a2` contains entries that are not present in `a1`? Currently, they will be missing from the result, but it might be irrelevant if both hashes are guaranteed to contain exactly all the same id/name combinations.

Comment: @PatrickOscity I would like to ignore entries not present in a1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite cleanly using a few of Ruby's built-in methods.

```
a1 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@hotmail.com" },
      { ID: 12497, name: "Lola",   email: "lola@hotmail.com" },
      { ID: 12498, name: "Hank",   email: "hank@hotmail.com" }]

a2 = [{ ID: 12497, name: "Lola",   ORDER_NO: 5511427 },
      { ID: 12496, name: "Robert", ORDER_NO: 5511426 }]

index = a2.group_by{|entry| [entry[:ID], entry[:name]] }
a1.map{|entry| (index[[entry[:ID], entry[:name]]] || []).reduce(entry, :merge) }
```

Result:

```
[{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :email=>"robert@hotmail.com", :ORDER_NO=>5511426},
 {:ID=>12497, :name=>"Lola",   :email=>"lola@hotmail.com",   :ORDER_NO=>5511427},
 {:ID=>12498, :name=>"Hank",   :email=>"hank@hotmail.com"}]
```

---

Breakdown:

First, we use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to build a table of the entries in a2 that could potentially be merged into entries in a1. We index this table on the id and name keys, since those are the factors we're using to determine which entries match:

```
index = a2.group_by{|entry| [entry[:ID], entry[:name]] }
```

This produces the result:

```
{[12497, "Lola"]=>[{:ID=>12497,   :name=>"Lola",   :ORDER_NO=>5511427}], 
 [12496, "Robert"]=>[{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :ORDER_NO=>5511426}]}
```

Next, we [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) each entry in `a1` to its new form, with the order numbers in the index merged:

```
a1.map{|entry|
  # ...
}
```

To get the value we're mapping each entry to, we start by getting an array containing all the values in `a2` which are suitable to merge with this entry from `a1`:

```
(index[[entry[:ID], entry[:name]]] || [])
```

This will return something like `[{:ID=>12497, :name=>"Lola", :ORDER_NO=>5511427}]` for Lola, and an empty array for Hank, who has no matching entry in `a2`.

Then, starting from the entry from `a1`, we [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) all the entries from the index to one hash using [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) (e.g. `reduce(entry, :merge)`), which results in an entry like `{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :email=>"robert@hotmail.com", :ORDER_NO=>5511426}`.

All this might seem a bit complicated if you're unfamiliar with the methods in Ruby's core library. But once you understand simple functional programing concepts like map and reduce, it's really not all that difficult to come up with simple and powerful solutions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

```
a1 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@hotmail.com" },
      { ID: 12497, name: "Lola",   email: "lola@hotmail.com" },
      { ID: 12498, name: "Hank",   email: "hank@hotmail.com" }]

a2 = [{ ID: 12497, name: "Lola",   ORDER_NO: 5511427 },
      { ID: 12496, name: "Robert", ORDER_NO: 5511426 }]
```

I suggest you first construct the hash:

```
h2 = a2.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[[g[:ID], g[:name]]]=g[:ORDER_NO] }
  #=> { [12497, "Lola"]=>5511427, [12496, "Robert"]=>5511426 }
```

then simply step through the elements of `a1`, adding key-value pairs where appropriate:

```
a1.each do |g|
  k = [g[:ID],g[:name]]
  g[:ORDER_NO] = h2[k] if h2.key?(k)
end
a1
  #=> [{ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@hotmail.com", ORDER_NO: 5511426},
  #    {ID: 12497, name: "Lola",   email: "lola@hotmail.com",   ORDER_NO: 5511427},
  #    {ID: 12498, name: "Hank",   email: "hank@hotmail.com"}]
```

I have assumed:

- no two elements (hashes) in `a1` have the same values for both `ID` and `:name`;
- no two elements (hashes) in `a2` have the same values for both `ID` and `:name`; and
- `a1` is to be muated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Rly good sample, but you have small error in your code. After last "each" method you must print 'a1' not 'a' :) +1

Comment: In the displayed result, why does Hank have an order number? I don't get that when running your code.

Comment: @Ajedi32, you're right: no order number for Hank. Thanks for the catch. I tested with Ruboto on a tablet, but haven't figured out here how to cut-and-paste its output. I made that mistake when transcribing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it faster by putting things in a hash by the requested attributes to merge before merging and then getting the values (of course there are assumptions re. the uniqueness of values in the input).

```
x1 = a1.reduce({}){|m, h| m[h.select{|k| [:ID, :name].include? k}] = h;m}
x2 = a2.reduce({}){|m, h| m[h.select{|k| [:ID, :name].include? k}] = h;m}
x1.merge(x2.select{|k,v| x1.key?(k)}){|k,o,n| o.merge(n)}.values
```

Running with your example data:

```
a1 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", email: "robert@hotmail.com" }]
=> [{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :email=>"robert@hotmail.com"}]

a2 = [{ ID: 12496, name: "Robert", ORDER_NO: 5511426 }]
=> [{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :ORDER_NO=>5511426}]

x1 = a1.reduce({}){|m, h| m[h.select{|k| [:ID, :name].include? k}] = h;m}
=> {{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert"}=>{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :email=>"robert@hotmail.com"}}

x2 = a2.reduce({}){|m, h| m[h.select{|k| [:ID, :name].include? k}] = h;m}
=> {{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert"}=>{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :ORDER_NO=>5511426}}

x1.merge(x2.select{|k,v| x1.key?(k)}){|k,o,n| o.merge(n)}.values
=> [{:ID=>12496, :name=>"Robert", :email=>"robert@hotmail.com", :ORDER_NO=>5511426}]
```